# How to compile GTK+ base application with musl-gcc?

Tags: gcc, gtk, gtk3, gcc7, musl

I compiled this GTK+ Example App with both gcc & musl-gcc. Both of those produced a binary file, but musl-gcc produced binary does not execute correctly & shows bunch of errors.

***Note: I installed both musl-libc and libgtk3 dev version.***
***Note: ldd command logs are allmost same for both gcc & musl-gcc produced binary files.***

**GTK+ Example App:**

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data) {
   GtkWidget *window;
   window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
   gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
   gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 600, 600);
   gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);

    return status;
}
```

**Comilation Command:**

> musl-gcc -Wall -g -o main main.c -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0

**musl-gcc produced binary log:**

```
Error loading shared library libgtk-3.so.0: No such file or directory (needed by ./main)
Error loading shared library libgdk-3.so.0: No such file or directory (needed by ./main)
Error loading shared library libpangocairo-1.0.so.0: No such file or directory (needed by ./main)
Error loading shared library libpango-1.0.so.0: No such file or directory (needed by ./main)
Error loading shared library libatk-1.0.so.0: No such file or directory (needed by ./main)
Error loading shared library libcairo-gobject.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by ./main)
Error loading shared library libcairo.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by ./main)
Error loading shared library libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0: No such file or directory (needed by ./main)
Error loading shared library libgio-2.0.so.0: No such file or directory (needed by ./main)
Error loading shared library libgobject-2.0.so.0: No such file or directory (needed by ./main)
Error loading shared library libglib-2.0.so.0: No such file or directory (needed by ./main)
Error relocating ./main: gtk_application_new: symbol not found
Error relocating ./main: gtk_application_window_new: symbol not found
Error relocating ./main: g_application_get_type: symbol not found
Error relocating ./main: g_type_check_instance_cast: symbol not found
Error relocating ./main: g_application_run: symbol not found
Error relocating ./main: gtk_window_set_title: symbol not found
Error relocating ./main: gtk_window_set_default_size: symbol not found
Error relocating ./main: g_signal_connect_data: symbol not found
Error relocating ./main: gtk_widget_show_all: symbol not found
Error relocating ./main: g_object_unref: symbol not found
Error relocating ./main: gtk_window_get_type: symbol not found
```

***ldd* command log for gcc produced binary:**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe90ff4000)
libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f9f93fec000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9f93c4d000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9f939f9000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9f93608000)
libgdk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f9f93312000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9f9310e000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f9f92f01000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f9f92bc9000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f9f929b9000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f9f927b3000)
libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f9f925aa000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f9f9228d000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9f92069000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f9f91e43000)
libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9f91c12000)
libepoxy.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007f9f91911000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f9f916fb000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f9f914ae000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f9f91269000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9f90f53000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9f90bb5000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9f90996000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9f90779000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f9f90551000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f9f90336000)
libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f9f900e2000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f9f8feda000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9f94af6000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f9f8fcd7000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f9f8facc000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f9f8f8c2000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f9f8f6bf000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f9f8f4bc000)
libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f9f8f27d000)
libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f9f8f075000)
libwayland-egl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f9f8ee73000)
libwayland-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f9f8ec64000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f9f8ea52000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9f8e84a000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9f8e646000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f9f8e392000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f9f8e16a000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f9f8dec5000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f9f8dc93000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f9f8da90000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f9f8d883000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f9f8d679000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f9f8d42c000)
libatspi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007f9f8d1fc000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f9f8cf5e000)
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f9f8cd55000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f9f8cb23000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f9f8c8b1000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f9f8c664000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f9f8c460000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f9f8c25a000)
libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f9f8bfd6000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f9f8bda9000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f9f8bba2000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f9f8b99b000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f9f8b786000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f9f8b560000)
liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f9f8b344000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f9f8b029000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f9f8ae14000)
```

***ldd* command log for musl-gcc produced binary:**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeaf2ca000)
libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f03c1a9f000)
libgdk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f03c17a9000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f03c159c000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f03c134f000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f03c1129000)
libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f03c0f20000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f03c0c03000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f03c09df000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f03c0640000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f03c03ec000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f03c00d6000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f03bfce5000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f03bfae1000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f03bf7a9000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f03bf599000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f03bf393000)
libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f03bf162000)
libepoxy.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007f03bee61000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f03bec4b000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f03bea06000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f03be668000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f03be449000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f03be246000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f03be03b000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f03bde31000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f03bdc2e000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f03bda2b000)
libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f03bd7ec000)
libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f03bd5e4000)
libwayland-egl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f03bd3e2000)
libwayland-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f03bd1d3000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f03bcfc1000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f03bcdb9000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f03bcb05000)
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f03bc8fc000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f03bc657000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f03bc425000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f03bc222000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f03bbffa000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f03bbded000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f03bbbe3000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f03bb9c6000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f03bb79e000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f03bb583000)
libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f03bb32f000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f03bb127000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f03baeb5000)
/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f03c25a9000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f03bacb1000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f03baa64000)
libatspi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007f03ba834000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f03ba596000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f03ba364000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f03ba15d000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f03b9f59000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f03b9d53000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f03b9b06000)
libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f03b9882000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f03b9655000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f03b9440000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f03b9239000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f03b9013000)
liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f03b8df7000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f03b8adc000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f03b88c7000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass the compilation arguments by hand. This is what `pkg-config` is made for, and what is advised in the [Compiling GTK+ Applications](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-compiling.html) section of the docs.

So you should do instead:

```
musl-gcc -g -Wall $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) main.c -o main $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)
```

Search for `../etc/ld-musl-$(ARCH).path` [Musl manual](https://www.musl-libc.org/doc/1.0.0/manual.html).

---

Here's also an extract from the [FAQ](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/faq.html):

> Where is ldd?
>
> musl’s dynamic linker comes with ldd functionality built in. Just
>   create a symlink from ld-musl-$ARCH.so to /bin/ldd. If the dynamic
>   linker was started as “ldd”, it will detect that and print the
>   appropriate DSO information.

Now it seems musl has a different ldconfig that doesn't use your standard paths, which would explain your problem. You could use the `-L` option of gcc to workaround that and specify in which directories to search for libraries, but a better way would be to learn how the linker and musl work together, so that the compiler looks at the right places. `ldd` will be of no use, it's using the linker config for the libc, not for musl.